# target dynamic input element in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am new to both programming / testing world as well as on stackoverflow. Please go easy! :)

So I am trying to write my first robo-framework-test where I am trying to fill in the signup page of [gmail](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/?pc=topnav-about-en)

[target page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fouH9.png)
[image]

My Problem is that this page i generated dynamically hince ther is no *fixed* input box which i can target, tried couple of methods after search online targeting `css / xpath` to fill in but none worked.

Here is what i have written so far :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    this is basic test case
Library          Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***

user have to create gmail account
    [Documentation]    first user have to register in gmail

    open browser                   https://www.google.com/gmail/about/       firefox
    click element                  xpath=/html/body/nav/div/a[3]
    ${nam}                         get text   css:input#FirstName
```

Console output ( error )

```
(robo-fm) my-lappy:robo-fm lappy$ robot -d Results  Tests/gmail.robot 
==============================================================================
Gmail :: this is basic test case                                              
==============================================================================
user have to create gmail account :: first user have to register i... | FAIL |
Element with locator 'css:input#FirstName' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gmail :: this is basic test case                                      | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

I am on `python` scripting for test environment using `mozilla` as my test browser. 
Please let me know any pointers in right direction. Thank you!

Comment: for a newbie..i liked the way question is presented!

Comment: When I go to the signup page, the input seems to always have the id of `FirstName`. Are you saying that when you visit the page, sometimes the id is different?

Comment: No. I target the `id` using `click element                  xpath=//*[@id="FirstName"]` but it always throws error `Element with locator 'xpath=//*[@id="FirstName"]' not found.`

Comment: Perhaps the element is not in the DOM the moment you try to access it; try to poll for it before getting it. E.g. use `Wait Until Element Is Visible   your_locator`, before using the `Get Text`.

Comment: BTW, why do you try to get the text of an `input` element, what are trying to accomplish? :)